# Prevent fetch credential (httponly cookies) used by third party plugins/extensions

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, fetch, httponly

Is there any best practice to implement session login that prevents third-party plugins/extensions send requests to the server?

I see cookies with `httpOnly` flag can prevent javascript interaction, along with `sameSite` flag can mitigate cross-site attacks, but what about the browser plugins/extensions?

Some plugins/extensions can call `fetch` inside their code, and `httpOnly` cookies are auto sent by fetch if the credentials are set to `include`, so any plugins/extensions that create a fetch with credential included, can request to the server to manipulate user data?

```js
# some_bad_plugin.js

fetch(YOUR_SERVER_URL, {
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: 'include',
})
```

I think this problem may be mitigated by additional login information stored in `cookie` or `localStorage`, and the request to the server need these fields. But that seems back to the beginning with no `httpOnly` cookie...

Is there something I missed?

Comment: `fetch(YOUR_SERVER_URL, {
  method: 'GET',
  credentials: 'include',
})` will indeed send httpOnly cookies that came from `YOUR_SERVER_URL` to `YOUR_SERVER_URL` - what's the issue? the cookie came from there - a browser won't send a cookie to site B that was set in site A

Comment: Nothing you can really do about it. Same as a person opening the console and running code there.

Comment: Thank's for your reply. So that's vulnerable if some browser extension got compromised, right? Malicious attackers may inject some script request your current page server, store the information and send it back to them.

Comment: I think the point I want to say is httpOnly flag doesn't mean "safe" but still needs other works together to prevent malicious requests?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to setting the cookie to include HttpOnly and Secure attribute if  server sets the sameSite=Lax attribute for the cookie , then the cookie will only be included in in top level navigation and not in any cross-site fetch

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#lax